# Bash globbing - autoexpand for a few specific cases?

Tags: bash, filenames, glob, expansion

I understand that the wildcard `*` (by itself) will expand in such a way that it means "all non-hidden files in the current folder" with hidden files being those prefixed by a period.

There are two use cases that I would think are useful, but I don't know how to properly do:

1. How can you glob for... "All files in the current folder, including hidden files, but not including `.` or `..`"?
2. How can you glob for... "All hidden files (and only hidden files) in the current folder, but not including `.` or `..`"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To expand on [paviums answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586477/bash-globbing-autoexpand-for-a-few-specific-cases/1586499#1586499) and answer the second part of your question, all files except `.` and `..` could be specified like this:

```
{.[!.]*,*}
```

Depending on your exact use case it might be better to set the `dotglob` shell option, so that bash includes dotfiles in expansions of `*` by default:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ echo *
.tst
```

Comment: `{..?*,.[^.]*,[^.]*}` works regardless of `dotglob` setting and avoids missing filenames starting with two dots, which everybody here seems to have missed.

Comment: @ephemient: That gives me a spurious match `..?*` when there are no filenames starting with two dots.

Answer (score 3):

The [Bash Cookbook](http://www.bashcookbook.com/) suggests a solution to your 2nd requirement.

```
.[!.]*
```

as a way of specifying 'dot files' but avoiding `.` and `..`

Of course, `ls` has the `-A` option, but that's not globbing.

Comment: `touch ..blah; echo {.,}[!.]* | grep blah` fail.

Answer (score 2):

Combining sth and pavium answers

```
# dot files but avoiding . and ..
.[!.]*

# all files but avoiding . and .. 
{.[!.]*,*}
```

Answer (score 1):

To meet your first case:

```
echo {.,}[^.]*
```

or

```
echo {.,}[!.]*
```

**Edit**:

This one seems to get everything, but is shorter than **ephemient**'s

```
echo {.*,}[^.]*
```

Comment: `touch ..blah; echo {.,}[^.]* | grep blah` fail.

Answer (score 0):

By "all files" and "all hidden files" do you mean files-only, or do you mean both files and directories? Globbing operates on names irrespective of it belonging to a file or a directory. The other folks give good answers for using globbing to find hidden vs non-hidden names, but you may want to turn to the `find` command as an easier alternative that can distinguish between the types.

To find "All files in the current folder, including hidden files, but not including . or ..":

```
find . -type f
```

To find "All files and directories in the current folder, including hidden files, but not including . or ..":

```
find . ! -name .
```

To find "All hidden files (and only hidden files) in the current folder, but not including . or ..":

```
find . -name '.*' -type f
```

To find "All hidden files and directories (and only hidden files and directories) in the current folder, but not including . or ..":

```
find . -name '.*' ! -name .
```

Note that by default find will recurse through subdirectories, too, so if you want to limit it to only the current directory you can use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

So, even though this is old - without using shopt, this doesn't seem to have been answered fully. But, expanding on what has been given as answers so far, these work for me:

1:

`{*,.[!.]*,..?*}`

2:

`{.[!.]*,..?*}`