# ln with dotfiles?

Tags: wildcard, symlink, glob, ln, dotfiles

I have a directory with several "dot files". I would like to symlink all these files.

I tried

```
$ ln -s /usr/dotfiles/* /usr/test
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/test/*' to `/usr/dotfiles/*': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
ln -s /usr/dotfiles/.[!.]* /usr/test
```

Inspired from

[`pavium’s answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586499)

Comment: You may also want to specify a destination, otherwise if the last "file" expanded by that glob is actually a directory it will be taken as the destination.