# git rm * doesn't remove all files in one go

Tags: git

I was trying out some sample instructions of git and came across this peculiar case that when we do a `git rm *`, it doesn't delete the `.*` files in the first attempt.
Why is it so?

```
mkdir -p test_repo1/folder && cd test_repo1
touch .testfile1 .testfile2 testfile3 folder/testfile4 folder/.testfile5
git init && git add . && git commit -m "test commit"
```

If now I do a `git rm` as follows, I have to do it a second time to remove all the files

```
$ git rm -r *
rm 'folder/.testfile5'
rm 'folder/testfile4'
rm 'testfile3'

$ git rm -r *
rm '.testfile1'
rm '.testfile2'
```

Why doesn't git remove all files in the first attempt itself? Also, why is this happening for files withing the repo root only?

Interestingly, if all I have are those `.testfiles`, then git removes them in the first attempt itself.

I am using git version `1.7.9.5`

Comment: the * will be interpreted by your shell, Check its globbing rules

Comment: control x will expand the * so you can see it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1586569/1301972

Comment: None of the answers mention the solution: If you want the `*` to be interpreted by git, you need to quote or escape it: `git rm -r '*'`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The wildcard gets expanded by your shell, and the expansion does not include dot files, by default, in most shells.

So by the time `git` executes, the first command has become

```
git rm -r folder testfile3
```

and the second probably a literal

```
git rm -r *
```

which `git` then expands by itself.

As [remarked by Keith,](/questions/19363795/git-rm-doesnt-remove-all-files-in-one-go/19363922#comment28697047_19363795) to remove everything in one go, prevent the shell from expanding the wildcard so that `git` does the expansion the first time already. This can be done with double or single quotes, or with a backslash before the asterisk. I tend to prefer single quotes:

```
git rm -r '*'
```

Answer (score 6):

### Shell Globbing

When you run `git rm *` you are actually using the shell's globbing rules to pass arguments to [git-rm(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html). Many shells don't include hidden files (e.g. files with leading dots) by default. In Bash, you can change the globbing rules with [dotglob](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) and [GLOBIGNORE](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-GLOBIGNORE). For example:

- Using the *shopt* builtin:

  ```
  # set dotglob
  shopt -s dotglob

  git rm *

  # unset dotglob
  shopt -u dotglob
  ```
- Using the *GLOBIGNORE* variable (which also sets *dotglob*):

  ```
  # Run git within a modified environment that includes GLOBIGNORE.
  GLOBIGNORE='.git' git rm *
  ```

Answer (score 4):

As user1281385 noted in a comment, the shell expands `*` the first time around.

The reason the *second* time removes the dot-files is that once there are no files to match, the shell leaves the literal asterisk as an argument (depending on your shell anyway, at least one variant errors out instead) and git then does its own matching.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the right syntax should be `git rm -r .` ('dot')

More worrying is `git rm -r` (empty pathspec string) which does the same until Git 2.11!

See [commit d426430](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d426430e6ec2a05bf0a4ee88c319dd6072908504) (22 Jun 2016) by [Emily Xie (`emilyxxie`)](https://github.com/emilyxxie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3b1e135](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b1e135b879c401c8e6c0b9acbaefc81054c3d37), 26 Oct 2016)</sup>

> ### `pathspec`: warn on empty strings as pathspec

> An empty string as a pathspec element matches all paths.
> A buggy script, however, could accidentally assign an empty string to a variable that then gets passed to a Git command invocation, e.g.:

```
path=... compute a path to be removed in $path ...
git rm -r "$paht"
```

> which would unintentionally remove all paths in the current directory.

> The fix for this issue requires a two-step approach.

> - As there may be existing scripts that knowingly use empty strings in this manner, the first step simply gives a warning that (1) tells that an empty string will become an invalid pathspec element and (2) asks the user
>   to use "`.`" if they mean to match all.

> - For step two, a follow-up patch several release cycles later will
>   remove the warning and throw an error instead.

---

Update for Git 2.15.x/2.16 (Q1 2018):

The message "will be made invalid in upcoming releases" disappear, and becomes:

```
empty string is not a valid pathspec.
please use . instead if you meant to match all paths
```

See [commit 9e4e8a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e4e8a64c2b9043b7ae2b6476efd9214c6738505) (07 Jun 2017) by [Emily Xie (`emilyxxie`)](https://github.com/emilyxxie).
See [commit 229a95a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/229a95aafa77b583b46a3156b4fad469c264ddfd) (23 Jun 2017) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 728c573](https://github.com/git/git/commit/728c57380338eed1aaad6047046ca71826e8066c), 06 Nov 2017)</sup>

> An empty string as a pathspec element matches all paths.
> A buggy script, however, could accidentally assign an empty string to a variable that then gets passed to a Git command invocation, e.g.:

```
path=... compute a path to be removed in $path ...
git rm -r "$path"
```

> which would unintentionally remove all paths in the current
> directory.

---

A git subcommand like "[`git add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f00809500f35ed2dbef9e58ae07ca2b6dcc82776/Documentation/git-add.txt#L96)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p))</sup> spawns a separate git process while relaying its command line arguments.
A pathspec with only negative elements was mistakenly passed with an empty string, which has been corrected with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022).

See [commit b02fdbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b02fdbc80a41f73ceb6c99e8e27b22285243a335) (29 May 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f008095](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f00809500f35ed2dbef9e58ae07ca2b6dcc82776), 07 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`pathspec`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b02fdbc80a41f73ceb6c99e8e27b22285243a335): correct an empty string used as a pathspec element

> Pathspecs with only negative elements did not work with some commands that pass the pathspec along to a subprocess.
> For instance,
>
> ```
> $ git add -p -- ':!*.txt'
> ```
>
> should add everything except for paths ending in "`.txt`", but it gets complaint from underlying "diff-index" and aborts.
>
> We used to error out when a pathspec with only negative elements in it, like the one in the above example.
> Later, [859b7f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/859b7f1d0e742493d2a9396794cd9040213ad846) ("`pathspec`: don't error out on all-exclusionary pathspec patterns", 2017-02-07, Git v2.13.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/015fba38345c685275864e5b216c74e8ba0633bb) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3bc53220cb2dcf709f7a027a3f526befd021d858)) updated the logic to add an empty string as an extra element.
> The intention was to let the extra element to match everything and let the negative ones given by the user to subtract from it.
>
> At around the same time, we were migrating from "an empty string is a valid pathspec element that matches everything" to "either a dot or ":/" is used to match all, and an empty string is rejected", between [d426430](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d426430e6ec2a05bf0a4ee88c319dd6072908504) ("`pathspec`: warn on empty strings as pathspec", 2016-06-22, Git v2.11.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b1e135b879c401c8e6c0b9acbaefc81054c3d37) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cc2e70264e0fcba04f9ef791d144bbc8b501206)) and [9e4e8a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e4e8a64c2b9043b7ae2b6476efd9214c6738505) ("`pathspec`: die on empty strings as pathspec", 2017-06-06, Git v2.16.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/728c57380338eed1aaad6047046ca71826e8066c) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2ece9dc4de60ead431f7902c273be32c880eede)).
> I think [9e4e8a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e4e8a64c2b9043b7ae2b6476efd9214c6738505), which happened long after [859b7f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/859b7f1d0e742493d2a9396794cd9040213ad846) happened, was not careful enough to turn the empty string [859b7f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/859b7f1d0e742493d2a9396794cd9040213ad846) added to either a dot or "`:/`".
>
> A care should be taken as the definition of "everything" depends on subcommand.
> For the purpose of "`add -p`", adding a "`.`" to add everything in the current directory is the right thing to do.
> But for some other commands, "`:/`" (i.e.
> really really everything, even things outside the current subdirectory) is the right choice.
>
> We would break commands in a big way if we get this wrong, so add a handful of test pieces to make sure the resulting code still excludes the paths that are expected and includes "everything" else.