# .gitignore not ignoring files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitignore

Here is my .gitignore file:

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
!/log/.keep
/tmp

# Ignore application configuration
/config/application.yml
/config/application.yml.bak
*.bak
```

Now, my repository is at https://github.com/rmohan80/learn-rails

Why would my latest commit -- "add configuration for email" add Readme.rdoc.bak but ignore .gitignore.bak

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

The star character does do match files beginning with a period.
You can add `.*.bak` to ignore them in your case or you can change the glob option in your shell :

```
# capture dot file
shopt -s dotglob

# do git stuff here

# stop capturing dot file
shopt -u dotglob
```

A similar problem solved here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19365350

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear. However, the problem isn't with the shell intrepretation - a ls *.bak shows all the files with .bak correctly - i.e. 4 files - including .gitignore.bak and Readme.rdoc.bak

Comment: @zooter, git uses slightly different rules. For example the leading / does not mean you are excluding a file somewhere in the root-path of your filesystem. Just give Slagt's first suggestion a try. Modify one of the newly excluded files and run a "git status" to see that nothing gets reported as modified.

Comment: Not seem to be working - I added .*.bak and output C:\Users\ram\ruby\learn-rails [master +3 ~2 -0 !]> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   README.md.bak

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        README.md.bak.bak
        config/environments/development.rb.bak
        config/secrets.yml.bak

Answer (score 1):

You have to checkout the HEAD, so that your repository looks unmodified. Then run the following:

```
$ echo '*.*.bak' >> .gitignore
```

To exclude files that are formatted like *README.md.bak*.

And run

```
$ echo '**/*.bak' >> .gitignore
```

to exclude files that are formatted like *README.bak* anywhere in the tree below the current directory.

Having .bak.bak files is something you don't want.